# Ignore response headers when using Dio in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter

I have a server sending the following value invalid content type in its header

```
application/json; UTF-8
```

Because of this, I am getting the following error from Dio

```
 DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: Error on line 1, column 24: Invalid media type: expected "=".
```

Here is how I am doing the request:

```
static Future createNewUser(String name, String email, String password,
  String confirmPassword, bool acceptTerms) async {
Map<String, String> data = {
  "email": email,
  "password": password,
  "password_confirm": confirmPassword,
  "accept_terms": acceptTerms.toString()
};

return await new NetworkCommon().dio.post(
      "api/v1/user/register",
      data: data
    );
}
```

I do not have access to the server and I do not have much hope of the response being fixed anytime soon.

How would I get Dio to ignore the invalid content type? Or would it be possible to fix the content header before Dio tries to read it?

Comment: add the request for more details

Comment: All done. Let me know if you need any more info..

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `responseType` in `options` as,

```
final response = await dio.post(
    baseUrl + 'api/v1/user/register',
    data: data,
    options: Options(
      method: 'POST',
      responseType: ResponseType.PLAIN,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Setting the responseType to ResponseType. PLAIN worked for me. 
Can you update your answer so I can accept it?  It might help someone in the future.

Comment: @DrkStr made the changes to the answer

Comment: @Kavin-K this solved the problem but can you add some explanation why this happens?